# spacing in numpy array

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a beginner question for numpy arrays. Why does the output have random spacing in between the elements and commas?

input:

```
list_weight_pounds = [150, 140, 220, 205, 265]

array_weight_pounds = np.array([150, 140, 220, 205, 265])
array_weight_kg = array_weight_pounds / 2.2046
array_weight_kg
```

output

```
array([ 68.03955366,  63.50358342,  99.79134537,  92.98739   ,
       120.20321147])
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because the default `floatmode` is [`'maxprec'`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

> ‘maxprec’: Print at most precision fractional digits, but if an element can be uniquely represented with fewer digits only print it with that many.

You can set it to `'fixed'` to get trailing zeroes instead of spaces:

```
np.set_printoptions(floatmode='fixed')
array_weight_kg
#array([ 68.03955366,  63.50358342,  99.79134537,  92.98739000,
#       120.20321147])
```

You can also use the [`printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.printoptions.html) context manager. See [`set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) for further formatting options.